# Tokenize (lex? parse?) a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby I'd like to take a Regexp object (or a String representing a valid regex; your choice) and tokenize it so that I may manipulate certain parts.

Specifically, I'd like to take a regex/string like this:

```
regex = /var (\w+) = '([^']+)';/
parts = ["foo","bar"]
```

and create a replacement string that replaces each capture with a literal from the array:

```
"var foo = 'bar';"
```

A naïve regex-based approach to parsing the regex, such as:

```
i = -1
result = regex.source.gsub(/\([^)]+\)/){ parts[i+=1] }
```

…would fail for things like nested capture groups, or non-capturing groups, or a regex that had a parenthesis inside a character class. Hence my desire to properly break the regex into semantically-valid pieces.

Is there an existing Regex parser available for Ruby? Is there a (horror of horrors) known regex that cleanly matches regexes? Is there a gem I've not found?

*The motivation for this question is a desire to find a clean and simple answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311794/replace-capture-with-value-then-return-the-entire-matched-pattern/11313732#11313732).*

Comment: An interesting question. Are regular expressions regular expressions themselves?

Comment: @acheong87 Given arbitrarily-nested capturing groups, I think not. My knowledge of the formalisms around regular languages is, however, very limited.

Comment: have you looked into regex variable interpolation?

Comment: @Iain No; I'm not even sure what that is. Google searches imply that this may be a Perlism (I'm in Ruby). Could you elaborate?

Comment: As far as I know, @Iain is just referring to interpolation inside regular expressions: `/foo#{var}bar/`, no?

Comment: Not that I know how that would help, so I may be wrong. Or he may be asking if that is something that needs to be matched by your library? Ignore me, I'm just guessing

Comment: @Gareth Ah, perhaps. Based on the requirements of this question, based on the one that I linked to, this is not an option. The regex source and replacement values are coming from external sources (e.g. a DB) not hand-typed.

Comment: What I'm saying, is that you might be able to do some of the replacements by having the literals held in variables that are then interpolated into the regex, instead of parsing the regex - which sounds like a nightmare!

Comment: @Gareth was correct with his first (astute:) guess +1

Comment: @acheong87: regular expressions as defined by Kleene are not themselves a regular language, because they have nested balanced parentheses. However, I'm pretty sure that Ruby `Regexp`s, which are much more powerful than regular expressions *can* parse Ruby `Regexp`s. Whether that is a good idea is a different question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have a JavaScript project on GitHub called: [Dynamic (?:Regex Highlighting)++ with Javascript!](https://github.com/jmrware/DynamicRegexHighlighter/) you may want to look at. It parses PCRE compatible regular expressions written in both free-spacing and non-free-spacing modes. Since the regexes are written in the less-feature-rich JavaScript syntax, these regexes could be easily converted to Ruby.

Note that regular expressions may contain arbitrarily nested parentheses structures and JavaScript has no recursive regex features, so the code must parse the tree of nested parens from the-inside-out. Its a bit tricky but works quite well. Be sure to try it out on the [highlighter demo page](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighterTester.html), where you can input and dynamically highlight any regex. The JavaScript regular expressions used to parse regular expressions are documented [here](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html).