# Ruby Pattern Matching- Finding number of all possible matches

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

Does anyone know how to find the number of all possible matches for a certain Regex pattern? What I mean is something like this:

**Calculator_1_([0-1])** *returns 2 possible outcomes because it can match two different inputs:*

```
 -Calculator_1_0
 -Calculator_1_1
```

**Calculator_1_([0-2])** *returns 3 possible outcomes because it can match three different inputs:*

```
 -Calculator_1_0
 -Calculator_1_1
 -Calculator_1_2
```

**Calculator_1_(.*)** *returns infinite because it can match infinite inputs:*

```
 -Calculator_1_0
 -Calculator_1_1
 -Calculator_1_2
 -Calculator_1_3
 -Calculator_1_a
 ...
```

Edit: Btw this is just an example.

Comment: In the general case, the result will be infinite, so I don't believe there is some out-of-the-box functionality that can be applied. What are you trying to achieve with this? Can you provide some background?

Comment: Well it's a very complex program, but basically I need the computer to be able to select the best pattern out of a series of user generated regex patterns. In order to do that though, I need to know which patterns have the least amount of possible matches and which, therefore, are the most precise. In my example above, both the first and the second patterns will match "Calculator_1_0" but the first one is more precise because it has the least amount of matches. Think of it as a regular expressions tool.

Comment: i think that the possible combination of even very trivial examples is so complex that you can't predict that with a simple algorithm...

Comment: +1 for a very interesting question, even if (in my opinion) no good solution for the question itself exists.

Comment: Without the target data you can't determine what a regex will match. What might appear to have infinite hits in advance might turn out to only have one if the data was sufficiently random or varied, and vice-versa. For your question, the data and patterns are too closely coupled to be able to answer it without both.

Comment: Not to worry, all Regex patterns will be tested beforehand to see if they match the input and only the ones that do will remain. Still, I'll probably end up with a lot of matching patterns which is why I need to find out which one best matches the input and to do that I need to know the total number of possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

No functionality like this exists built into any Ruby library (that I know of). To do this properly you would need to [parse the regular expression into pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314350/tokenize-lex-parse-a-regular-expression), to be able to properly differentiate (for example) between:

```
 /1+/   # Infinite possibilities
 /1\+/  # 1 possibility
 /1\\+/ # Infinite possibilities
 /[1+]/ # 1 possibility
```

Once that was done it would be a relatively "simple" job to early out for any regex that had a `*`, `+`, or `{n,}` qualifier, convert all (relevant) `?` and `{n,m}` qualifiers to exact counts, convert all `[…]` character classes to sets of numbers, and expand out (multiply) the results within `a|b` alternations and `(a?b){2,3}` grouped expressions.

Given the currently inability to easily and correctly parse the regular expressions, however, this concept is dead in the water. So too, I fear, is your idea. Time to find another way to solve your problem.

What about, for example, using threads for all regular expressions along with the block form of `scan` to handle the matches in parallel, stopping and aborting all further scans with the earliest completion?

Comment: Well the problem is that I am running a series of user generated patterns against a user generated string, and I need to find which pattern "best matches" it. I do know for a fact that it is possible since any logic based code, like Regular Expressions, can be broken down to basic mathematics and from there you can calculate all possible outcomes. However, this doesn't make the it any less complex.